# Is there a way to look inside of the file in <form action="processor.php>

Tags: php, reverse-engineering

So lets say I have a file: form.php and inside of it there is a `<form action="processor.php>` that parses the data from this form to processor.php

How can I see insides of processor.php the way it is implemented? The actual code inside of it?

EDIT:

I should have mentioned that it is hosted on someones website.

Comment: Open processor.php in a text editor, if you have access to it

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If that were the case, everyone would be hacking (*pardon the expression*) each others' sites "right & left". NO, you can't view the actual code's source files, unless you're on their server's root, OR... the person who made the PHP (code), doesn't have PHP enabled on their site, then will the source appear; not good practice. Test-test and re-test till the cows come home.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way you can do it is if you have control of the file. If not, no, you cannot see the source code of that file.

Comment: Unless PHP was down and the server up... which would be pretty awkward.

Comment: So if I have a really smart PHP application hosted I do not need to worry about it being stolen? How does it work?

Comment: @ToTCaMbIu - see killneel's answer. The web server will process your code itself, and only send the finished content to the browser. Aside from a mis-configured server or a hacker, your code will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to this file via a browser (i.e. This is someone else's code that you are trying to look at), then you are out of luck.

PHP code is processed by the web-server which produces a HTML output which is sent to your browser. The actual PHP code is never returned by the web-server (unless there are configuration errors in the web server).

Answer (score 0):

If that file resides somewhere outside of your control you cannot even really be sure that it is a PHP file, there could have been some clever URL rewrite rules set in place to make it appear that files that get served are PHP.

And that is completely intentional, in that file will often be things like passwords for the database connection. Most sites these days work as three tier architectures, the first tier is your browser (the client), then there is the web server, and behind it is the database. The database is intended to be hidden from the view of the client. This is why, for example, you should never generate SQL statements on the client side (for example in Javascript), but rather only pass information to the web server, which then determines how to structure it to read/write from the DB.